# Limit $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2-k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Determine 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^2}+ \frac{2}{n^2-1} + \frac{3}{n^2-2} + ... + \frac{n}{n^2-n+1} \right)$$

**My thoughts**

I can rewrite this limit as follows
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2-k+1}$$
Furthermore, I know that $0<\frac{1}{n^2-k+1} \leq 1$ and for $1 \leq k \leq n: \frac{1}{n^2-1+1} \leq \frac{1}{n^2-k-1} \leq \frac{1}{n^2-n+1}$. I wanted to use the squeeze theorem, but I seem to get stuck. Any help?

Comment: @postmortes That's not a typo I think

Comment: The way I'd attempt to solve the question (initial instinct) is to re-write as: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_i^n(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{i}{n^2-i+1})$$

Comment: @MitchellFaas You must not exchange summation and limit.

Comment: Why not just trying squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering large values of $n$, let us compute the Taylor series (or even long division)
$$\frac{k}{n^2-k+1}=\frac{k}{n^2}+\frac{k^2-k}{n^4}+\frac{k^3-2
   k^2+k}{n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^8}\right)$$ Now, use the classical formulae for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^a$ and you will very quickly see what is the limit when $n\to \infty$. Even the first term will give it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

Put
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n^2-x+1},\enspace S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf_n(k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2-k+1}$$
Then $f_n(x)$ increases in $[1,n]$, hence
$$S_n-f_n(n)<\int_1^nf_n(x)\,dx < S_n$$
since $f_n(n)\approx 1/n$, it suffices to compute the limit of the integral as $n\to\infty$.
The integral can be computed directly:
$$\int_1^n\frac{x}{n^2-x+1}\,dx=(n^2+1)\log\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-n+1}\right)-n+1$$
and after some work, one finds that the limit of the r.h.s equals $\frac{1}{2}$.
As a result, $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over n^{2} - k + 1} & =
-\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over k - n^{2} - 1} =
-\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n + \pars{n^{2} + 1}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k - n^{2} - 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n + \pars{n^{2} + 1}
\sum_{k = -n^{2}}^{n - n^{2} - 1}{1 \over k}} =
-\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n - \pars{n^{2} + 1}
\sum_{k = n^{2} - n + 1}^{n^{2}}{1 \over k}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n - \pars{n^{2} + 1}
\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n^{2}}{1 \over k} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n^{2} - n}{1 \over k}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n - \pars{n^{2} + 1}
\pars{H_{n^{2}} - H_{n^{2} - n}}}\qquad\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic Number~}
\end{align}
With the [Harmonic Number Asymptotic Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation):
\begin{align}
&-n + \pars{n^{2} + 1}\pars{H_{n^{2}} - H_{n^{2} - n}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
-n + \pars{n^{2} + 1} \times
\\[2mm] &\ \braces{\bracks{\ln\pars{n^{2}} + \gamma + {1 \over 2n^{2}}} - \bracks{\ln\pars{n^{2} - n} + \gamma + {1 \over 2\pars{n^{2} - n}}}}
\\[1cm] = &\
-n + \pars{n^{2} + 1}\bracks{-\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over n}} -
{1 \over 2n^{3}\pars{1 - 1/n}}}
\\ \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&
-n + \pars{n^{2} + 1}\pars{{1 \over n} + {1 \over 2n^{2}}} =
-n + \pars{n + \color{#f00}{1 \over 2} + {1 \over n} + {1 \over 2n^{2}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
\bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}